# UIScrollView content insets for iPhoneX (safeAreaLayoutGuide)

Tags: ios, swift, iphone-x

I have a `UIScrollView` that is constraint to `view.topAnchor`, so it scrolls up to the top edge of an iPhoneX. However, when I add content to the scrollView (such as a UIImage), and constraint it `scrollView.topAnchor` the content is inset to the safeAreaLayoutGuide. This seems to happen with scrollViews since if I take the content out and place it in the view, it also moves to the screen edge.

Anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the view controller's `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` to false in viewDidLoad (`self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false`). From the documentation:

> The default value of this property is true, which lets container view controllers
>   know that they should adjust the scroll view insets of this view controller’s
>   view to account for screen areas consumed by a status bar, search bar, navigation
>   bar, toolbar, or tab bar. Set this property to false if your view controller
>   implementation manages its own scroll view inset adjustments.

UPDATE:

As was mentioned, `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` is deprecated in iOS 11+. You can do a version check and to fix it for older versions of iOS as well. Example:

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
} else {
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
}
```

Comment: Very cool. This works! But I think `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` has been depreciated. I used `scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never`

Comment: One thing to note with this is that the `contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior` and `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` effect all sides, not just the top. That may or may not be a desired side effect depending on the scenario.